# Django 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product' error

Tags: python, django

I want to add medicine to my cart from a medicine list. I created a view but when I click add button it gives this error:

> AttributeError at /cart/6/ 'QuerySet' object has no attribute
> 'product'

I want that when a user click + button, medicine will be add users cart. Here are my codes. Please help me.

**cart/models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    user = models.TextField(User)
    product = models.OneToOneField(Medicine,primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**cart/views.py**

```
def update_cart(request, id):
    current_user = request.user
    cart = Cart.objects.all()

    try:
        medicine = Medicine.objects.get(id=id)
    except Medicine.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    cart.product.add(medicine)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/cart")
```

**medicines/models.py**

```
class Medicine(models.Model):

    medicine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_info = RichTextField(verbose_name="Details")
    medicine_image = RichTextField(verbose_name="Image")
    medicine_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_qr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_price = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)
```

**medlist.html**

```
 <td> <a href="/cart/{{medicine.id}}" class="btn btn-sq-xs btn-success">
              <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i><br/>
            </a> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=current_user)
```

returns a `Cart` queryset (read the docs on [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter)), but what you need is a `Cart` instance.

For that you can use the method [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get)

```
cart = Cart.objects.get(user=current_user)
```

or [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first)

```
cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=current_user).first()
```

---

Note that you will have the same issue with the line

```
medicine = Medicine.objects.filter(id=id)
```

so you need to change this line as well to get a `Medicine` instance.

Comment: I fixed the code and now I get different error. get() returned more than one Cart -- it returned 3!

Comment: @eda That means that there are 3 carts for the selected user. If you only want one cart of these, then use the second method I suggested using `.first()`

Comment: now, 'Medicine' object has no attribute 'all' in "if not medicine in cart.product.all:"  I am so sorry but I must fix it please help me.

Comment: @eda For this last error you probably need to change the field in the `Cart` model from a `OneToOneField` to a `ManyToManyField`, because i assume a cart can have multiple medicines and a single medicine can be in multiple carts.

Comment: @Ralph returned to the first mistake